change map height and its zoom level dynamically in angular
I have a map div in angular component html:
<div id="map" [ngStyle]="{'height.px': mapHeight}"></div>

mapHeight is initialized to 600, and I have button that, once being clicked on, will change mapHeight from 600 to 300, and from 300 back to 600, etc.
The map div size is changed just fine. However, how to make the content within the map, ie zoom level, center, etc to change accordingly with the div size? For example, if on size 600, I can see the full lake, but once shrink to size 300, I do not want to see half of the lake, I want the scale to change accordingly so that I can ALWAYS see the full lake (smaller full lake on smaller div, vice versa).
How to do this in angular.
My attempts: I used ngclass that linked to a css style, which also does not work. I found that only inline style with "height:300px" works for me. But as I said,  I want it to respond to DOM ui change.

Figured out a solution, but not sure if it is efficient: use ViewChild to reference the map div container and inside ngAfterViewInit(), create an resizeobserver to watch over the map div:         const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
this.map.invalidateSize();
});
resizeObserver.observe(this.mapDiv.nativeElement);

Isn't it better to do that via function call? Something like: map.setView([0, 0], 0);?

@mat.hudak. I have tried this, but the effect is not that good. I want to let map content change RELATIVELY to the change in map div container. It is like as if you are "dragging" the bottom right corner of the div and shrinking or expanding it as your mouse moves, during which the map content (scale, size of the road, icons, etc) also change accordingly. I do not think setview can achieve such accurate and smooth effect. Like why you choose zoom level as 0? You are guessing what what the zoom level can be if I shrink the div. But I want leaflet to calculate it for me.
